# How to avoid re-renders at the App level when I make a change to a child component (like a searchbar)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a searchbar React component that doesn't trigger an App-wide re-render when I type, yet allows me to use the query in other components/to make an API call.

Background:

- I learned that stateless input components are good for reusability and creating controlled components. So state stays at parent (or App) level and the component's value gets passed in via props.
- On the other hand, tracking the query's state at the App level causes ALL components to re-render (when the input's `handleChange` calls `setQuery`) and feels like a needless use of resources.

What am I missing here? Do I leave the query piece of state at the SearchBar level instead? Should I use React.memo or useCallback?

**SearchBar component:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Searchbar = ({ query, handleQueryChange }) => {
    return (
        <div className="field">
            <label>Enter search term</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleQueryChange} value={query}></input>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Searchbar;
```

**And the App component**

```
const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const handleQueryChange = (e) => {
         setQuery(e.currentTarget.value);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        function search() {
             ...makeAPIcallwith(query).then((result) => {setResults(result)})
        };
        if (query) {
            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                search()}, 1000);
            return () => clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, [query]);
    return (
        <div className="content-container">
            <SearchBar query={query} handleQueryChange={handleQueryChange} />
            <...Other React component not needing to re-render... />
        </div>
       );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I cannot stress enough: You **SHOULD NOT CARE** about renders unless you run into 1) performance issues (use `useMemo` or `React.memo`) or 2) logical issues (you're doing something else wrong and should fix the other thing). If neither of these two things applies to you, don't waste your time.

Comment: Not that that rant is out of the way, why do you have the query state up there? I'm willing to bet something else in that `App` uses it. If it does not, then `query` doesn't even need to be state anywhere and you can just use an uncontrolled input component. Do you have a form that you're submitting somewhere? Is there any more code or is this example just contrived?

Comment: `yet allows me to use the query in other components/to make an API call` - then it sounds like something else in `App` uses `query` - is there an `effect` that you're not showing?

Comment: Yes, there is something else in App that uses it. I wasn't sure what to include or not in this example - there's a LOT more code in my project, I have a bunch of nested components and another piece of state for an API call results. Will edit now

Comment: This is well organized react code and would get a +1 from me in code review. There are no problems to be found or optimizations to be made here.

Answer (score 0):

The tiniest optimization that you could make here is this:

```
    const handleQueryChange = useCallback((e) => {
         setQuery(e.currentTarget.value);
    },[]);
```

It's not worth making. What you've shown is good idomatic react code.

I guess the other thing that you could do, if you haven't already because you haven't shown the code, is to help React out by encapsulating the results in a component like this:

```
    return (
        <div className="content-container">
            <SearchBar query={query} handleQueryChange={handleQueryChange} />
            <ListOfThings results={results}/>
        </div>
       );
```

Super tiny components, so tiny they seem almost trivially simple, is the name of the game in React. If your components are over 30-40 lines long, then